# Draw a circular dashed lines in Moai sdk

Tags: lua, moai

I don't know how to draw a circular dashed lines in moai using MoaiDraw? Could anyone tell me how to do that? sorry I'm a newbie in moai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try out with your version of MOAI

```
MOAISim.openWindow ( "test", 320, 480 )



viewport = MOAIViewport.new ()

viewport:setSize ( 320, 480 )

viewport:setScale ( 320, 480 )



layer = MOAILayer2D.new ()

layer:setViewport ( viewport )

MOAISim.pushRenderPass ( layer )



function onDraw ( index, xOff, yOff, xFlip, yFlip )

        MOAIDraw.fillCircle ( 0, 0, 64, 32 )

end



scriptDeck = MOAIScriptDeck.new ()

scriptDeck:setRect ( -64, -64, 64, 64 )

scriptDeck:setDrawCallback ( onDraw )



color = MOAIColor.new()

color:setColor(1, 0, 0, 1)



prop = MOAIProp2D.new ()

prop:setDeck ( scriptDeck )

layer:insertProp ( prop )



prop:setAttrLink(MOAIColor.INHERIT_COLOR, color, MOAIColor.COLOR_TRAIT)
```

Comment: i 've try your code, but it draw a full red circle, not a circular dashed lines?

Comment: @EdwardNight, do you have it in a pic?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJent.png you can see it, it's just a red circle

Comment: @EdwardNight, i mean what's your expected output you're looking for, could you show an example.

Answer (score 0):

FreedomPride : it's just a red circle .